# How use spaces instead of underscores in file names?

Tags: workflow, file-browser

I'm referring to this "feature" https://developer.blender.org/T45900

It was not happening before, but it is now, and it is messing up the structure of some folders I previously created. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: If it's a regression that's braking things then it sounds rather bugish to me. Even if it's intended as a "feature", afaik most programs don't do this.

Comment: What version appears to be doing this? I can't reproduce this in 2.76 RC1 on archlinux (or any other previous version I've tried)

Comment: I'm getting this in a git build of 2.76 (not update for a few days). I use a PPA to provide the builds but otherwise should be nothing different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug was fixed (at 2015-10-15), so the easiest solution is to download nightly build of Blender: https://builder.blender.org/download/ . I have tried it and now I finally can save my files as usually. The fix also will be available in 2.76a and later releases. Alternatively, you can build Blender yourself. The bug was fixed by this patch: https://developer.blender.org/rB767d3f23b7efb4e993574c29ebbbe0a4d90f5e50 .