# Blender 2.76 - Stop adding underscores?

Tags: python, interface, customization, file-browser

I upgraded my version of blender to 2.76, and to my horror, quickly discovered it replaces spaces in the file names with underscores. **Is there a way I can turn this off?**  Even a script would do!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39081/how-use-spaces-instead-of-underscores-in-file-names